How to make a crack on a glass sphere?
Hello to all my dear friends
I have a problem in creating a crack on the surface of the glass ball that I made in the blender, and I will also put the reference that I am using for you to see.
My problem is that I want to animate the cracking on the surface of the ball, that is, I have the option to change the method from low to high cracking, and I can make any adjustments I like.
I think it can be made with Geometry Nodes, but I don't understand. Do you think it is possible to do something like this with Geometry Nodes or any other method that you know would be better? I would appreciate it if you could help me.
Video (external link)


Have a look here : How to create a crack in the ground that develops over time ? It is based on the extension "Cell Fracture".

Yes,Thanks buddy, I saw this, but I want to apply it on a Sphere, not a flat surface, and I also want to know if there are other ways to get better results.

Do you want "just" to render cracks, or to make mesh islands ?

I want the robot that is inside the sphere to increase the number of cracks by punching the sphere

But not breaking it. So Markus von Broady's proposal seems a valuable answer based on shading instead of modelling.

Thank you buddy

Using Voronoi in "distance to edge" mode is a good start to simulate cracks. Then you can limit those cracks to some distance from a given point, or to some weight-paint etc. I limited it to a distance transformed by another voronoi to have zones.
Then there's a question what happens with the cracks: do they stop being transmissive? does their angle change? I changed their normals by reusing a voronoi but I ran out of inspiration...



Thank you for your help so far...
Look, I want to make a robot inside the ball like what we have in the picture as a reference for the animation. Now everything is done, I have only one problem, and that is that I want the robot to hit the glass ball with three punches by hitting the first punch on its hand and a little bit around it. make a crack on the glass and by hitting the second punch, the amount of cracks will increase and by hitting the third punch the glass will fall completely down. I used cell fracture to make this work, but I didn't get a good answer.

@Maxendeer you can animate the parameters within the shader to make the cracks grow.

Yes thanks buddy
Just Can I specify their location with weight paint?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r6hPEx1JW5KU4tdqM-fbAEO7N8RfDbSL/view?usp=sharing                   this is a video link

In the video, there is a punch to break the glass, I want to punch two before it breaks
